# C# - TakeWhile and SkipWhile not returning?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a class RekenReeks which returns numbers starting from 2, multiplied by 2. So {2,4,8,16,32,64}

Now I learned about the TakeWhile and SkipWhile methods as well as LINQ.

So I have created 3 variables which should store exactly the same but my `Console.WriteLine` only prints selection1 and not 2 and 3.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RekenReeks reeks = new RekenReeks(2, n => n * 2);
            var selection = from i in reeks
                        where i > 10
                        && i < 1000
                        select i;

        var selection2 = reeks.TakeWhile(n => n < 1000 && n > 10);

        var selection3 = reeks.SkipWhile(n => n > 1000 && n < 10);

        foreach (int i in selection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("selection1 {0}",i);
        }

        foreach (int i in selection2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("selection2 {0}", i);
        }

        foreach (int i in selection3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("selection3 {0}", i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class RekenReeks : IEnumerable<int>
{
    Func<int, int> getNew;
    int number;
    public RekenReeks(int starton, Func<int, int> getNewThing)
    {
        getNew = getNewThing;
        number = starton;
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return number;
        for (; ; )
        {

            yield return getNew(number);
            number = getNew(number);

        }

    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: you are enumerating your `IEnumerable` multiple times.

Comment: So it should be solved by creating 3 instances of the `IEnumerable`?

Comment: that would do it yes.

Comment: @DanielA.White What are you talking about? Multiple enumeration is fine, you don't have another choice with an endless sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `TakeWhile()` and `SkipWhile()` start from very beginning of the sequence and stop taking/skipping when condition doesn't meet.

```
  // I've redesigned your ReekenReeks
  // [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ..., 2**30]
  var reeks = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 30)
    .Select(index => 1 << index);
```

For instance, if you put

```
  var selection2 = reeks
    .TakeWhile(n => n < 1000 && n > 10);
```

since the 1st item of the `reeks` is `2` the condition `n < 1000 && n > 10` doesn't meet `TakeWhile` stops and returns an *empty* sequence. The right implemenation is

```
  var selection2 = reeks
    .SkipWhile(n => n <= 10)
    .TakeWhile(n => n < 1000);
```

If you want to cut off values from the *middle* of the sequence (`selection3`) you have to use `Where`:

```
  var selection3 = reeks
    .Where(n => !(n > 1000 && n < 10)); // cut theses items off
```

Be careful when printing out an *infinine* sequence, `.Take()` is a good choice here:

```
   var selection3 = reeks
    .Where(n => n > 1000 && n < 10)
    .Take(100); // First 100 items in case the sequence is too long
```

Comment: @Ivaro18: in your code `SkipWhile(n => n > 1000 && n < 10)` skips *nothing* (condition doesn't meet for the 1st item - `2`) and then `TakeWhile(n => n < 1000 && n > 10)` takes *nothing* as well, since the 1st item is `2` and the condition doesn't meet

Comment: `var selection2 = reeks.SkipWhile(n => n <= 10).TakeWhile(n => n < 1000);` returns an empty sequence. I do understand what I was doing wrong

Comment: I've run the code (with my `reeks`) and I've got `[16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]` for the `selection2`; `Console.Write("[" + String.Join(", ", selection2) + "]")`;

Comment: With your reeks it works indeed, but why doesn't it with mine?

Comment: Oh excuse me, I still had the `yield break` in my `RekenReeks.getEnumerator()`. After removing this, it works with my class as well

Answer (score 7):

Your sequence is unlimited (theoretically). You assume too much. The functionality of your program cannot possibly know that your sequence is strictly monotonic increasing.

```
var selection = from i in reeks
                    where i > 10
                    && i < 1000
                    select i;
```

This will never stop. Because the `where` will always pull the next value, it does not know it's condition will be satisfied, it always *has* to check the next value.

```
    var selection2 = reeks.TakeWhile(n => n < 1000 && n > 10);
```

This will take values, while they are between 11 and 999. As your sequence starts with 2, it will stop right on the first value.

```
    var selection3 = reeks.SkipWhile(n => n > 1000 && n < 10);
```

This will skip values while they are between 11 and 999. As the first is 2, it will skip none and therefore yield *all*.

Comment: how can I stop my LINQ expression from running?

Comment: @Ivaro18 Why do you want to? What do you expect from stopping it? If you told us what you *wanted* to do and what you *expect* to happen, we might suggest other options.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selection = from i in reeks
  where i > 10
  && i < 1000
  select i;
```

There's no reason for this to ever end. When `i` is 1024 it won't be yielded, but it will still check then if `2048` is less than `1000`, or `4096` is less than `1000`, or `8192` is less than `1000` and so on forever (eventually either overflow exception happens or `n` wraps around to `0` which then keeps being set to `0 * 2` which is still `0`).

```
reeks.TakeWhile(n => n < 1000 && n > 10)
```

The first value tried is `2`. This does not satisfy the predicate `n < 1000 && n > 10` because it is not true that `2 > 10`. Therefore the taking stops.

```
reeks.SkipWhile(n => n > 1000 && n < 10)
```

There is no value of `n` for which `n > 1000 && n < 10`. Therefore this is the same as having no `SkipWhile` at all.

It seems like what you want is:

```
reeks.SkipWhile(n => n >= 1000 || n <= 10).TakeWhile(n => n < 1000 && n > 10)
```

Which skips until the first number that meets the criteria is found, then takes all that meet it until the first that does not.

Comment: `var selection2 = reeks.SkipWhile(n => n >= 1000 || n <= 10).TakeWhile(n => n < 1000 && n > 10);` using this line still returned an empty sequence for some reason

Comment: Solved by removing `yield break`, another user submitted that as an answer and I didn't remove it

Comment: Ah. I was puzzled there. I'd gotten the sequence 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512. (You can get the same sequence slightly faster with `reeks.SkipWhile(n => n <= 10).TakeWhile(n => n < 1000)` but that's by basing the answer on knowledge of the sequence coming. I answered with the superfluous parts because it then fits the basic pattern of `.SkipWhile(predicateMatchingAllUnwanted).TakeWhile(predcateMatchingWanted)`.